# OrientDB: Can't use "update ... put ... " together with "where" clause

Tags: database, nosql, orientdb

My update query is:

```
update test put phone = 'office','+123456' where name = 'luca'
```

The error message is:

```
Found unexpected keyword 'NAME' while it was expected '[=]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT. Try it ;-)

Comment: There is no 1.2 tag in orient-db svn repository. How can I get it?

Comment: It's the current snapshot that will be released as final on the first week of October. It's the trunk in the SVN repository.